# trying to change a .mov file to .mp4 when uploading it - python/django

Tags: python, django

First time asking a question here... SO,

I have a `django web app` where people can upload video files. The video file upload just fine and when they are .mp4 files, they can click on them and immediately play them in the chrome browser. However, if the video file is .mov, it forces the user to download the file to their computer before viewing it. I have tried to capture the file before is saves and change the filename from .mov to .mp4 but its not working.

```
form = AddAttachmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    attachment = form.save(commit=False)
    attachment.user = student
    attachment.attacher = self.request.user
    attachment.date_attached = timezone.now()
    attachment.competency = competency
    attachment.filename = request.FILES['attachment'].name
    if attachment.filename.endswith('.mov'):
        attachment.filename.replace('.mov','.mp4') 
 attachment.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
import os

form = AddAttachmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    attachment = form.save(commit=False)
    attachment.user = student
    attachment.attacher = self.request.user
    attachment.date_attached = timezone.now()
    attachment.competency = competency
    filename = request.FILES['attachment'].name
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()
    if ext == '.mov':
        attachment.filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.mp4'
    else:
        attachment.filename = filename
    attachment.save()
```

This should change the file extension as you want, but I don't think changing extension have any effect for browser, because it will check the **mime type** as well.

Comment: Thanks! This worked and answered the question I presented but as you pointed out, it failed to actually change the file type on the backend. Once the file is uploaded, it shows .mp4 on the front end but its still stored as .mov in the database (aws s3 bucket) so it will end up downloading the video file rather than being able to watch it in browser.

Comment: So this changed the filename put it did not change the URL. for example it says "videofile.mp4" on the front end but it is still stored as "videofile.mov" in the url (https://s3.amazonaws.com/mywebapp/videofile.mov). Maybe we can try to change the URL as well and that would work? Or maybe we need to also change the underlaying MIME type?

Comment: @KollynLund Chnging the mime type requires to actually _convert_ the `.mov` to `.mp4`. You can do that using `ffmpeg`. But the url should be ok, are you using `<instance>.attachment.filename.url` to access the url?

Comment: Yes I am using attachment.filename.url to access the URL. I am guessing I can change the URL the same way we changed the filename? And once I do this i will see if this fixes the issue. If not, I will have to look into ffmpeg to actually convert the file.

Comment: Thanks. it looks like I will need to use ffmpeg to do what I need. It would also make sense to use come of the other features found in ffmpeg like compression of large files, ability to open up users webcam to film videos, etc. Do you have any suggestions for libraries to use ffmpeg specifically with Django?

Answer (score 0):

This way you are just creating an extension.mov.mp4

use os.path.splitext(), os.rename()

```
import os
thisFile = "mysequence.mov"
base = os.path.splitext(thisFile)[0]
os.rename(thisFile, base + ".mp4")
```

Comment: this helps and does what I thought I needed it to do but this does not change the MIME type. I think that is the culprit. We can change the file name but its still stored as an .mov file. I am looking into how to change the MIME type right now.

Comment: So this changed the filename put it did not change the URL. for example it says "videofile.mp4" on the front end but it is still stored as "videofile.mov" in the url (https://s3.amazonaws.com/mywebapp/videofile.mov). Maybe we can try to change the URL as well and that would work? Or maybe we need to also change the underlaying MIME type?